# Unable to hide article author in joomla 3.x

Tags: templates, joomla, article

i'm using joomla 3.x installation and i wish to hide the author when displaying articles by the way i'm using ja purity III theme if it matters

Comment: Did you try something? Usually turning parameter "Show Author" to "Hide" in Article Manager Options helps.

Comment: yes i already did it

Comment: Make sure you also do that in any menu item and in the article itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Joomla article options are given priority like this:

```
=>global settings
=>=>article settings (override global settings)
=>=>=>menu settings (override item settings)
```